# MemoryViews and Garbage Collection in Python

Tags: python, garbage-collection, python-3.6, memoryview

Basically:

If I declare a bytearray somewhere:

`arr = bytearray(somestr)`

Then create a memoryview of it:

`view = memoryview(arr)`

Can I be sure that for as long as I have a reference to the view object somewhere, that the bytearray will remain?

i.e:

```
def foo():
    arr = bytearray("hello world")
    return memoryview(arr)

view = foo()
```

Will garbage collection ever remove the original bytearray? Or does this count as a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It counts as a reference. *However* you can call [`release()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.release) on the view to remove that reference:

```
>>> class A(bytes):
...     def __del__(self):print('called')
... 
>>> a =A()
>>> m = memoryview(a)
>>> del a
>>> m
<memory at 0x7fddcb00a288>
>>> len(m)
0
>>> m.release()
called
```

Note that you can access the underlying object from the view using the [`obj` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.obj).

In generaly, anything that is not described explicitly as a [weak reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#module-weakref) holds an actual reference. In memory-managed languages that's the default.

Comment: Thank you so much!